# Switch Statement Only Defaults c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, default

So I'm writing some code and I have this switch statement to set some bools in a 2d array. I have a nested for loop and a switch with switches in the nested loop setting on outer loop `int i` and inner loop `int e`. `grammar[i][e]` I'm switching on i and then on e but for some reason it just defaults on me. I have it printing out i and e.. and it still just defaults so there must be something wrong with my switch statements but I'm not seeing the issue here.

```
bool follows = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    // 1 noun, 2 pronoun, 3 verb, 4 adverb, 5 adjective, 6 preposition, 7 conjunction, 8 determiner, 9 interjection, 10 exclamation, 11 notype, 12 auxiliary
    for (int e = 0; e < 12; e++)
    {
        //std::cout << " This is where we're at in grammar array " + std::to_string(i) + " and " + std::to_string(e);
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0: // noun // noun
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            case 1: // pronoun //pronoun
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            case 2: // verb // verb
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            case 3: // adverb //adverb
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            case 4: // adjective //adjective
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            case 5: // preposition //preposition
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            case 6: // conjunction //conjunction
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = true; // change
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = false; // change
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            case 7: // determiner //determiner
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            case 8: // interjection //interjection
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            case 9: // exclamation //exclamation
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            case 10: //NoType //NoType
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            case 11: //auxiliary
                switch (e) {
                    case 0: // noun
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 1: // pronoun
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 2: // verb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 3: // adverb
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 4: // adjective
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 5: // preposition
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 6: // conjunction
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 7: // determiner
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    case 8: // interjection
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 9: // exclamation
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 10: //NoType
                        follows = true;
                        break;
                    case 11: // auxiliary
                        follows = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            default:
                // TODO CHANGE THIS 
                std::cout << "Defaulting for some reason." + std::to_string(i) + " on i ";
                follows = true;
                break;
        }
        grammar[i][e] = follows;
        if (grammar[i][e]) { std::cout << std::to_string(i) + std::to_string(e) + " True "; }
        else { std::cout << std::to_string(i) + std::to_string(e) + " False "; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have forgotten the ***minimal*** part of your [mre]. And which of the many `switch` statements is it you have problems with?

Comment: They were all defaulting because I neglected to include break statements for the outer switch statements.

Comment: Your code could probably be gretly simplified using an array initialiser and possibly an enum for the word types: https://godbolt.org/z/6GrWY77Wh. Such large nested switch statements are difficult to read and maintain, if you really want to go that way I'd move each inner switch into a separate function

Comment: For-switch is strange construct, you might unroll to have more readable code (or just use initalizer_list) [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aG5d73M1z)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Alan. I'm using the switch statements as an array initializer actually and using a resolver function with enums. Reading in a file to adjust grammar syntax while running and using this switch to initialize or adapt during.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put breaks after all bigger switch statements.

```
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;  // <--- here
                case 1: // pronoun //pronoun
                    switch (e) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I just saw that myself as I posted this. lol